# Get the jsonObject stored as string in comment field in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

in another function I stored a string, which is a jsonObject:

```
SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='table'
```

the output from phpmyadmin is correct:

```
{"out_user":"pb","out_email":"test@test.com","out_date":"13.04.2015"}
```

the output in the echo of php is wrong:

```
$result = mysqli_query($coni, "SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='$tablename'");

    $test = json_encode($result);
    echo $test;

{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

why the phpmyadmin output is correct and the result in the php variable not? I need it to send the JSONObject as string to java.

Comment: What is the value of '$tablename' ? Where it does come from?

Comment: the syntax is right, and the '$tablename' is get by POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysqli_query() method's result is a mysqli result object: http://php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli-result.php

You will have to use http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php to get your actual database result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the result of mysqli_query() is a string normally or not? in my other request i am working with fetch_array and strings from it....

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)
echo $row->table_comment;

Comment: no, as you can read in the docu mysqli_query returns an an object. if you use fetch array you can either have an associative or an numeric array, where the containing values may be strings.